# SoapFault Fault occurred while processing. estoy consumiendo u servicios SOAP y me sale este error

Tags: laravel, soap

estoy haciendo un programa con Laravel donde debo consumir servicios SOAP, lo que sucede es que este tiene varios servicios y el primero es uno de Verificar Comunicación y este me funciona perfectamente, debo aclarar que este no me pide ningún parámetro, los demás si me piden parámetros pero ninguno me corre me sale el error **SoapFault
Fault occurred while processing.**
No se cual pueda ser el motivo.
Este es el código que estoy usando.

```
$wsdl ="https://pilotosiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo/v2/FacturacionSincronizacion?wsdl";

    $token = '********';

    $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, [ 
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create([ 
         'http'=> [ 
          'header' => "apikey: TokenApi $token"    
         ] 
         ]),

        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
    ]); 

    $respons = $client->sincronizarActividades(2,0,"0",0,"0",0);
    // $respons = $client->verificarComunicacion();
    dd($respons);
```

Adjuntaré imagen del servicio corriendo correctamente en SoapUI y el error que me da. Espero se entienda mi consulta y me puedan ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, sucedía que el servicio que estoy consumiendo tiene una estructura algo diferente a lo que yo pensé, y debía mandar un Array con los parámetros.

```
 $SolicitudSincronizacion = array(
        'codigoAmbiente'   => 2,
        'codigoPuntoVenta' => 0,
        'codigoSistema'    => '6D0BF9E8F5C161FDA740E6F',
        'codigoSucursal'   => 0,
        'cuis'             => 'CBF01EC5',
        'nit'              => 2447538015,
    );

    $result = $client->sincronizarActividades(
        array(
            "SolicitudSincronizacion" => $SolicitudSincronizacion,
        )
    );
```

adicionando este código corre correctamente.